# Contact form7 issue

Tags: wordpress

Why does the mail from the contact form 7 does,nt reaches the email address that belongs to the same domain of the WordPress site whereas with the individual gmail account it works fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webserver MTA is probably configured to relay email sent to this domain locally.
The easiest way to solve this issue is to use an external smtp service, or [Mandrill](https://mandrillapp.com) who provide an easy to use wordpress plugin: [wpmandrill](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpmandrill/).